# Assembly how to interpret a jump with register after label

Tags: pointers, assembly, syntax, x86-64, att

```
jmp    *.L4 (,%rdx,8)
```

I'm working on an assignment that has this as one of its unconditional jumps.
My questions are:

1. how does rdx * 8 affect the jump?
2. what difference does the * make before .L4?

Answer (score 2):

That's just an indirect jump through a table. As you hopefully know `.L4(,%rdx,8)` is a memory address, with value `.L4 + rdx * 8`. In 64 bit mode pointers are 8 bytes, hence the scaling factor. `rdx` is simply the index of the entry in the table.

The `*` doesn't make any difference except silencing an assembler warning :) You are supposed to use a `*` for indirect jumps, but when the assembler is able to figure it out, it will just give a warning. The `(,%rdx,8)` is a dead giveaway that this is an indirect jump. If you had `jmp *.L4` then the `*` would be required to differentiate it from `jmp .L4`. The former is an indirect jump through a pointer at `.L4`, while the latter is just a direct jump to `.L4`.

Comment: thanks for your answer. My question now is how do you calculate .L4 + rdx * 8? I'm confused because .L4 is a label, how does adding labels work? I should also add that all that .L4 holds is a number of (.quad    .L2) instructions (L2-L7). How do I know which label the indirect jump goes to?

Comment: As I said, `rdx` is the index. You only know which label it goes to if you know the value in `rdx`. If `rdx` is `0` it will go to the first label, if it's `5` it will go to the sixth label, etc.

Comment: @skob002 : All labels have an address.